# HttpHandler return 403 in SharePoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, httphandler

I have a site running in SharePoint 2010 that is using a HttpHandler.
When the site is started, everything runs just fine.

After a while, the HttpHandler starts to return 403 (Forbidden).

Manually recyling the application pool fixes the problem temporary, but it returns after approximately a day (depending on how much load there is on the site).

The funny thing is, that the problem only seems to affect HttpHandlers (both my custom handler and SharePoint's own HttpHandlers) - the aspx pages works just fine.

The HttpHandler is configured like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.ajax" type="LI_BR.UserControls.web.ajax.AjaxHttpHandler" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxHandler" path="*.ajax" verb="*" type="LI_BR.UserControls.web.ajax.AjaxHttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Checking the IIS logs, I've found this:

A successful call to the HttpHandler (just proving that it actually works sometimes)

```
2015-01-23 06:41:42 192.168.0.XX POST /Registration/SysFelt.ajax WorkerID=12&FeltID=1796&TabelID=&ObjektID=0 20113 DOMAIN\USER 192.168.0.XX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+InfoPath.2) 200 0 0 31
```

A failed request

```
2015-01-26 03:32:16 192.168.0.XX POST /Registration/SysFelt.ajax WorkerID=12&FeltID=1796&TabelID=&ObjektID=0 20113 DOMAIN\USER 192.168.0.XX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+InfoPath.2) 403 0 0 5662
```

I've tried to find a pattern of when the 403 starts, and as far as I can tell, it happens if the first request after a recycle is to a HttpHandler. This is just a theory, and I got nothing else then indication from the logs of this pattern. After the first failed request every single request (even for other users) to any HttpHandler returns the same 403.

A snippet from the logs that indicates this pattern:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-01-26 03:32:16
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-01-26 03:32:16 192.168.0.XX POST /time/SysFelt.ajax WorkerID=12&FeltID=1796&TabelID=&ObjektID=0 20113 DOMAIN\USER 192.168.0.XX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+InfoPath.2) 403 0 0 5662
```

or (from the sister site - having the same problem)

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-01-27 06:30:10
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-01-27 06:30:10 192.168.0.XX POST /time/SysFelt.ajax WorkerID=12&FeltID=1796&TabelID=&ObjektID=0 20114 - 192.168.0.63 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+InfoPath.2) 401 1 2148074254 5849
2015-01-27 06:30:10 192.168.0.XX POST /time/SysFelt.ajax WorkerID=12&FeltID=1796&TabelID=&ObjektID=0 20114 DOMAIN\USER 192.168.0.XX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+InfoPath.2) 403 0 0 748
```

Note: last part of IP and domain/username has been edited in the log snippets. All log entries are for the same user though.

Note: the timestamp in the logs are off by 1 hour (09:00 becomes 08:00 in the logs) - not sure if that means anything.

The HttpHandler is currently using

```
public class AjaxHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } 
}
```

I have tried changing the IsReusable to true, and removing the IRequiresSessionState, so see if that makes any difference - it doesn't seem to.

I cannot figure out why this problem is happening, and I'm running out of ideas on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I'll post my solution here.

I never did figure out why the error happened, but I did seem to find a workaround. The workaround is closely linked to my theory that the error happened because the first call after a recycle, was to a HttpHandler.

The solution is simple, but not pretty at all.
I inserted a JavaScript on the pages where the HttpHandler could be called. The Script simply redirected to a page where the HttpHandler counldn't be called (in my case, the front page) after 20 minutes. This Means that the first request after a recycle always was to an aspx page - after that everything (including the HttpHandler) worked fine.